# How to start a calendar from a parent activity in Android popup window

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function that start a popup windows with a squareup CalendarView. I have to initialize the calendar on the popup in order to show, but I cannot initialize it at the xml file, it has to be in the activity.

I have already tried to get the initialization from an activity that is not the parent one, and I get the error saying that "Must have at least one month to display.  Did you forget to call init()?" I tried simply from the parent activity but I realize that I am not sending any initialization to the popup window so I get the same error.

Here is my xml file code

```
<com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:id="@+id/calendar_dates"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView>
```

Here is my function in my Pop activity, which is not the parent activity. I realize that if I can use this function in parent actity and send the datePicker iniatized, I might get what I am looking for.

```
fun settingDate() {
        val today = Date()
        val nextYear = Calendar.getInstance()
        nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)

        val datePicker = findViewById(R.id.calendar_dates) as CalendarPickerView

        datePicker.init(today, nextYear.time).inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE)

        datePicker.setOnDateSelectedListener(object : CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener {
            override fun onDateSelected(date: Date) {
                val calSelected = Calendar.getInstance()
                calSelected.time = date

                val selectedDate =
                    "" + calSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + (calSelected.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + " " + calSelected.get(
                        Calendar.YEAR
                    )
                Toast.makeText(mContext, selectedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onDateUnselected(date: Date) {

            }

        })

    }
```

I expect to get an array of dates from the popup window that I can assign to two DatePickers I have at the parent activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using an Fragment, and on the line that says v.findViewById(R.id.year_view...)as CalendarView, you get the view you want to use which in this case is the calendar. If you use it onw its own, by getting only the id, you will get a null pointer exception. That my friends is the way to initialize a Widget from a fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_date_frament, container, false)

    val today = Date()
    val nextYear = Calendar.getInstance()
    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)
    val mCalendarPickerView = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.year_view_calendar) as CalendarPickerView

    mCalendarPickerView.init(today, nextYear.time)
        .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE)


    mCalendarPickerView.setOnDateSelectedListener(object : CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener {
        override fun onDateSelected(date: Date) {
            val calSelected = Calendar.getInstance()
            calSelected.time = date

            val selectedDate =
                "" + calSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + (calSelected.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + " " + calSelected.get(
                    Calendar.YEAR
                )
            Toast.makeText(context, selectedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onDateUnselected(date: Date) {

        }

    })

    return v
}
```